# How do i increase the start function interval after score is 1000?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a javascript game, got some codes online and I am trying to refine it to what I want, so I want the interval to be faster after score gets to 1000. I have tried all my possible best to dig into this, please kindly help me to refine my code. The start function takes an interval of 20 miliseconds in the gamearea function. I do a count of scores, then when the scores get to 1000, i want to increase the interval by settiing it in the updateGame function

```
function startGame() {
    myGameArea = new gamearea();
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 75);
    myscore = new component("15px", "Consolas", "black", 220, 25, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

function gamearea() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.canvas.width = 320;
    this.canvas.height = 180;    
    document.getElementById("canvascontainer").appendChild(this.canvas);
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.pause = false;
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.start = function() {
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    }
    this.stop = function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.pause = true;
    }
    this.clear = function(){
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {

    this.type = type;
    if (type == "text") {
        this.text = color;
    }
    this.score = 0;    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    var x, y, min, max, height, gap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            myGameArea.stop();
            document.getElementById("myfilter").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("myrestartbutton").style.display = "block";
            return;
        } 
    }
    if (myGameArea.pause == false) {
        myGameArea.clear();
        myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
        myscore.score +=1;        
        if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
            x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
            y = myGameArea.canvas.height - 100;
            min = 20;
            max = 100;
            height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
            min = 50;
            max = 100;
            gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            myObstacles[i].x += -1;
            myObstacles[i].update();
        }
        myscore.text="SCORE: " + myscore.score;
        if (myscore.score == 1000){
            this.start = function() {
                this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 10);
            }
        }

        myscore.update();
        myGamePiece.x += myGamePiece.speedX;
        myGamePiece.y += myGamePiece.speedY;    
        myGamePiece.update();
    }
}


startGame();
```

Comment: this piece of code works this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);? If yes, i think you can do this this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, this.interval + 10); you need to add 10 to your previous interval value.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have small issues with it, when the game restarts, it still takes the new interval set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly stop the old interval running and start a new one.

```
    if (myscore.score == 1000){
        this.stop(); // Stop the old interval
        // Start a new interval with the new timing
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 10);
    }
```

Comment: I did this, and the interval changed, but then, when the game stops and needs to restart, it still uses the new interval and not the default of 20     if (myscore.score == 1000){

                myGameArea.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 19);
                
        }
        
        else{
            myscore.update();
            myGamePiece.x += myGamePiece.speedX;
            myGamePiece.y += myGamePiece.speedY;    
            myGamePiece.update();
        }

Comment: That is odd, if you use the this.stop() and this.start() methods as they appear in your example, it should go back to interval 20.  Have you made any other changes that aren't in the example?

Comment: i didn't make any change, but I've done a temporary fix, using window.location.reload()

Comment: you can check the full code on my repo https://github.com/pianistprogrammer/javascript-game and see what's wrong

Comment: Well, when you are updating the interval you aren't stopping the previously registered call back, so you are just creating a new interval as well

you should do something like :

                clearInterval(mGameArea.interval);
                myGameArea.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 30);